# Why won't Yarn run scripts from the package.json?

Tags: yarnpkg

My npm scripts are not working with Yarn.

Normally I would run `npm start` or `npm run build`and the scripts would execute successfully. When I try and run these with `yarn start` / `yarn run start` / `yarn run build` I get errors:

```
yarn start v0.15.1
$ "node server" 
sh: node server: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

I installed Yarn globally through npm. Running zsh in terminal.

**Update:** Looks like this was a v0.15.1 bug and is no longer an issue in 0.16.*

Comment: Do the commands it's attempting to run work outside of Yarn? i.e. What happens when you do `node server` in the CLI?

Comment: Do u hav node?.

Comment: Which terminal version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, `node server` runs no problem directly in terminal.

Comment: Does `npm run build` still work?

Comment: Related to the Issue : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1298

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your yarn package with npm or reinstall using brew.

I'm using nvm for npm/node and I had the same problem with v0.15.1. Solved it by upgrading yarn to v0.16.1.

Comment: This worked for me. I just ran `npm update --g yarn` and then tried `yarn start` again and it ran my start script. I had originally installed it with npm, so I updated it with npm.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in Yarn and is fixed in the following PR : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/1180

Update your yarn to 0.16.1 and test it. Hope it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was stuck with this issue during days. I did everything I saw in internet : reinstall yarn, updated it, try different commands, etc...

I want to precise that I am working on Ubuntu.

So what's worked for me : I saw that inside my root directory, there was a node_modules, package.json and other similar files so I just deleted them and after I run inside my react project : "yarn start" and It worked ! So becare full you dont have init in your root directory some files from your react-app and if yes, delete them.